# How to extract a string that is present before ".lower" in c#?

Tags: c#, string, lowercase, tolower

I have a string like

```
string variable1="EXAMPLE";
```

and later somewhere in my code, I use like

```
 Console.WriteLine(variable1.ToLower());
```

I may use `variable1.ToLower()` multiple times. But now I want to store the variablename that is converted to Lower in a separate new variable, that is, I have to extract `variable1` from `Console.WriteLine(variable1.ToLower());` line and store it in a string variable. Is that possible?

My main goal is that, If my code has `variable1.ToLower()` in too many places, then I have to run an application, that replaces all `variable1.ToLower()` to a new string that has the value of `variable1.ToLower()`. Please Note that using too many `variable1.ToLower()` in a code is a violation.So I am just creating a new variable to store the value of `variable1.ToLower()` and use that new variable instead of `variable1.ToLower()` in every place.

Comment: i don't think `ToLower()` modify your original string, it will create a new instance. try `string lowerCaseString = variable1.ToLower()`

Comment: I think its better just store the string in a public variable than retrieve it from `Console.WriteLine(variable1.ToLower());`

Comment: You want to extract the literal text `variable1` from that expression? Sounds like an XY question. What is your end goal here? Why do you need the name of the variable ?

Comment: @Rob I am using too many variables in my code. And I just want to get the variable that is converted to Lowercase.

Comment: So you are looking for a simple find & replace? You can do that with any text editor, even Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, why not just do this?

```
var lower = variable1.ToLower();
Console.WriteLine(lower);
```

Comment: There are too many strings in my code and I have to capture only the string that is converted to lower case. Can I extract a string or a phrase that is present before `.ToLower` in a line?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question after all. What is it that you want to do exactly? what is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

[String.ToLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a copy of the original string. So the original string is not modified and you can safely use it otherwise.

```
string variable1 = "EXAMPLE";
string lowerCaseVariable1 = variable1.ToLower();
Console.WriteLine($"Is still the original string: {variable1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is the lower case copy of the original string: {lowerCaseVariable1}");
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the name of the string variable instead of the content, you can use `nameof` ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)).

```
string variable1 = "EXAMPLE";
string nameOfVariable1 = nameof(variable1);
Console.WriteLine(variable1.ToLower());
```

Comment: Can I extract a string or a phrase that is present before `.ToLower` in a line? Will Regex help?

Comment: @Vishwaroopa: You mean something like `nameof(variable1)` ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx))?